# Set and update global jQuery cookie

Tags: jquery, cookies

I'm building a site that sets numerous cookies based on selections. The cookie updates and saves but when I navigate to another page the selections are not stored globally. I've tried using path: / and it only remembers the selections when I visit that page.

I'm storing a cookie that renders a list in a panel of selected options and its also stored in a hidden field.

I've got some code below, is the path in the correct place?

````
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    jQuery("ul.activities_list").append(jQuery.cookie("listItem"), {
                expires: 7,
                path: '/'
            }); //<---end of $.cookie);
  jQuery(".activity").on("click", ".add_activity", function() {

   // jQuery(".add_activity").live('click',function () {
        var title = jQuery(this).parent().parent().find('.title').html();

        // Add activity item to the panel list.
        jQuery("ul.activities_list").prepend(jQuery('<li>'+title+'<button id="remove_item" class="button is-primary is-white">Remove</button></li>'));

        jQuery.cookie("listItem", ((jQuery.cookie("listItem") ? jQuery.cookie("listItem") : '') + jQuery('<li>'+title+'<button id="remove_item" class="button is-primary is-white">Remove</button></li></li>').clone().wrap('<div />').parent().html(), '/'));
        jQuery.cookie("listItemTitle", ((jQuery.cookie("listItemTitle") ? jQuery.cookie("listItemTitle") : ', ') + title));
   console.log(jQuery.cookie("listItem")) });
    jQuery("#remove_item").live('click',function () {

        jQuery(this).parent().remove();
        var removed_item = jQuery('.activities_list').html();

        jQuery.cookie("listItem", removed_item);
        jQuery.cookie("listItemTitle", removed_item);

    });
});```
````

Comment: Regarding the use of .live(): Note: This API has been removed in jQuery 1.9; please use on() instead.

Comment: Thanks Rob, it's been commented out as it was a part of the original code and uses .on() as per the line above :)

Comment: For what it's worth, there is one more here:  `jQuery("#remove_item").live('click',function () {`

Comment: Doh, missed that, thanks for letting me know.

Comment: In a word, no, your code is not in the correct place `jQuery("ul.activities_list").append(jQuery.cookie("listItem") ` <-- ends jQuery.cookie call `, {
                expires: 7,
                path: '/'
            }` <-- used as a second parameter to `append` `);` <-- ends `append` call. I'm not sure why you're appending the result of `jQuery.cookie()` to an HTML element anyway, but that's a different problem.

Answer (score 0):

> This should help:

```
$.cookie("test", 1, {
   expires : 10,           // Expires in 10 days

   path    : '/',          // The value of the path attribute of the cookie
                           // (Default: path of page that created the cookie).

   domain  : 'jquery.com', // The value of the domain attribute of the cookie
                           // (Default: domain of page that created the cookie).

   secure  : true          // If set to true the secure attribute of the cookie
                           // will be set and the cookie transmission will
                           // require a secure protocol (defaults to false).
});
```

> To read back the value of the cookie:

```
var cookieValue = $.cookie("test");
```

> You may wish to specify the path parameter if the cookie was created on a different path to the current one:

`var cookieValue = $.cookie("test", { path: '/foo' });`  [How do I set/unset a cookie with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458724/how-do-i-set-unset-a-cookie-with-jquery)